# Netlogo - importing a CSV representing a matrix of side 2^n and setting the value of patches

Tags: csv, import, netlogo

My model work on a world that is always a square of side 2^N.

I'd like to have some code that will allow me to import a CSV like this:

```
3
5; 6; 8; 9; 8; 4; 1; 5
7; 7; 8; 2; 9; 5; 2; 6
5; 8; 4; 2; 6; 8; 9; 2
5; 4; 9; 8; 6; 3; 2; 4 
5; 6; 8; 9; 8; 4; 1; 5
7; 7; 8; 2; 9; 5; 2; 6
5; 8; 4; 2; 6; 8; 9; 2
5; 4; 9; 8; 6; 3; 2; 4
```

The value 3 represent N so the world size should be set as a square of 8 x 8 patches (2^3=8).

The patches owns the a variable named "value" and I'd like to set those values accordig to the values in the CSV.

Comment: Have you looked at the CSV extension, which is included in the new NetLogo release (version 5.2)? Also, there are tons of existing questions on Stack Overflow about reading CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Seth mentioned, the CSV-Extension can help here:

```
let matrix but-first (csv:from-file "filename.csv" ";") ; `but-first` since we don't care about that first line

ask patches [
  let row max-pycor - pycor
  let column pxcor - min-pxcor
  set value item column item row matrix
]
```